# Why is the next statement executed before yield?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm expecting the program to pause until yield is executed but it's not. The DisplayTileBacks() function runs while PauseGame() is being executed:

```
void Start()
{
... 
        DisplayTileFronts();
        StartCoroutine(PauseGame(3f));
        DisplayTileBacks();
}

public IEnumerator PauseGame(float waitTime)
{
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    float waitEndTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + waitTime;
    while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < waitEndTime)
    {
        yield return 0;
    }
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Starting a coroutine doesn't stop other scripts from running. If you want `DisplayTileBacks` to be called at the end of `PauseGame` you should put the call to it inside.

Comment: Starting a coroutine does not abort your `Start` method. Unity coroutines will execute any code between `yield return` statements on future video frames, depending on what kind of value you yield. You aren't pausing your program, you are pausing the advance of game time.

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based interpolation function instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit code similar to the following.

```
void Start()
{
... 
  
    StartCoroutine(Display(3f));
}

public IEnumerator Display(float waitTime)
{
    DisplayTileFronts();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime));
    DisplayTileBacks();
}
```

Comment: You can also make the Start as IEnumerator and move the Display code into it. Same same.